# Json function not passing the array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

```
var checkedValues = $('.required:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("testcata", "home")' +"?Type=" + "@(Session["typ"])" + "&city=" + "@(Session["cit"])" +  "&chkd=" + checkedValues,
 function (data) {
     //code
 })
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult testcata(string Type, int? city, int[] chkd)
{
   //code
}
```

I am trying to get the values of check-boxes which are checked to pass through json function.
 why the method in the controller taking null as an argument for more than one selected check values ? I am having a int[] chkd parameter in the function . It shows null.

Comment: I am not sure which server side language is this. But, you should only get `Type`, `city` and `chkd`  as `get` parameters, not as passed in function.

Comment: i m not sure but if you see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khu5oeLc/  see in console if checkbox is checked it is returning a array with  "on"..then instead of taking array of `int` on controller side change it array of `string` instead.

Comment: passing so much data in query string is really a bad idea. you can use `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` which should return `Json()` response. Try Making `Post` request to the method. In this sense you need to make some fair adjustments in your code.

Comment: @Jashwant This is asp.net mvc. On client side its jquery. Please help me

Comment: @Rohit416 - If I tick one check-box then its working but more than one its not. I am properly getting the json result in one check-box ticked case.

Comment: @Kartikeya - fiddle is not sowing anything when I put values to every check-box and click run

Comment: @Smokingmonkey..see console .. just right click inside fiddle and then select console tab and see there.

Comment: @Kartikeya - there is no console tab bro. On right click only browser options are there

Comment: I am not familiar with asp.net MVC, but `Request.Querystring['chkd']` should have the desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put an Array as a String. Try this:

```
var checkedValues = encodeURIComponent($('.required:checked').map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get().join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Please first turn your method from GET to POST and than follow code below.

**Your Existing Code**

```
var checkedValues = $('.required:checked').map(function () {
return this.value;
}).get();
```

**New Code to be added**

```
var Data = new Object();
Data.Type = @(Session["typ"]);
Data.city = @(Session["cit"]);
Data.chkd = checkedValues;


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/home/testcata",
data: JSON.stringify(Data),
dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data){
// Required Code 
});
```

**C# Code Changes**

```
public class Data
{
  string Type {get; set ;};
  int city {get; set ;};
  int[] chkd {get; set ;};
}


public ActionResult testcata(Data data)
{
   String Type = data.Type;
   int city =  data.city;
   int[] chkd = data.chkd; // Your Array will be successfully received here.
}
```

**Hope this will help you, Thanks :) Happy Coding**

Comment: Thanks for your kind help but I didn't want to change my getjson method as it is being used at various places in  project. I used join method and passed the string as param. now everything's fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a re-arrangement of your code.

```
var checkedValues = $('.required:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
//if you are getting correct values here than,

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home/testcata",
    data: JSON.stringify({chkd: checkedvalues}),
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data){
  // your stuff
});
```

Decorate your controller method with `[HttpPost]` if possible. Communicating with `JSON` data is quite secure though. :)

Comment: Don't think you need `JSON.stringify()` on `{chkd: checkedvalus}`. jQuery sends data just fine without that.

Comment: yep, agree. but i used `stringify()` for extra surety. :)